# How can I update a frame whenever a file is updated

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

So I am trying to code a chatroom for my school to use, and I have everything worked out except for one thing. You have to refresh the page for messages to show up.

I tried this:

```
<html style='background-color:#202020;'>
<word style='color:#FFFFFF;'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$log = file_get_contents('./log.txt');
echo $log;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

However, not long after, there were so many people online that my web server crashed (lol)

What this is doing is refreshing the page every two seconds infinitely, but that's obviously not a good idea. How might i be able to refresh this frame only when log.txt updates, so the site doesn't crash? Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try AJAX?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff I have tried looking around but I haven't found anything particularly useful.

Comment: For your target you must read about websocket

Comment: Websocket... I will do some research, thank you

Comment: Use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)